# Is it mandatory to return the view name from controller in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I went through the basic Spring mvc code from this link 
http://springinpractice.com/2008/05/05/build-a-shopping-cart-with-spring-web-flow-2-part-1/

Here I see that the controller method is blank & the request name & the jsp name is same. So automatically the jsp is rendered even when the controller is not returning the name. I don't understand this. Generally the controller is supposed to return the view name.

Can anyone explain this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply an option that Spring offers. Instead of having to explicitely tell it that the view name is "home", you have the option of not telling what the view name is. If so, by convention, Spring will look for a view that has a name deduced from the request mapping.

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver) for details.